# ByteArray in JNI

Tags: c#, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How can I write android native library in clear C?

I tryed write byte operation NOT. But face trouble with getting element of array.

In C#

```
private static byte[] NOT(byte[] b1)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[b1.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = (byte)(~b1[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In AndroidStudio .cpp I write:

```
static jbyteArray byteNOT(JNIEnv *env,jbyteArray b1)
    {
        int lengthOfArray = env->GetArrayLength(b1);

        jbyteArray ret = env->NewByteArray(lengthOfArray);
        for(int i = 0;i<lengthOfArray;i++){
        ret[i] = ~ ...
    }
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Use e.g. `GetByteArrayElements`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: Use env->GetByteArrayElements(b1, NULL) to get jbyte pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, for a sample code that gets data from Java and sends it back.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-013/

In your case, you need something like this:

```
/* get size of the array */
  jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);

  /* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
  jbyte *body = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, 0);

  /* do some stuff */
  for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("Byte value: %d\n", body[i]);

    /* update value */
    /* you will make negation here */ 
    body[i] = 0;
  }

  /* release body when you decide it is no longer needed
    Pass changes back to Java */
  (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, body, JNI_COMMIT);
```